# Embedded Youtube Video Fullscreen or Causing Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, fullscreen

I am building a homepage that automatically repositions the elements depending on the window width. The problem is that one element "player" has a YouTube video in it. I want users to be able to fullscreen the YouTube video, but after they click fullscreen the window resize is caught and that "player" element is repositioned which cancels the fullscreen.

Also, when this homepage is viewed on mobile devices any scrolling is triggering this same function for some reason. I would like to fix both issues.

Here is the JS code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var player = $('.header-11-sub .player');
    if ($(window).width() < 751) {
        $('.header-11-sub .signup-form').before(player);
        $('.header-11-sub .player-wrapper').hide();
    } else {
        $('.header-11-sub .player-wrapper').append(player);
        $('.header-11-sub .player-wrapper').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will fire the resize event when the browser enter and exit from fullscreen mode. This is the behavior for both Chrome and firefox as of now.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.fullScreen
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238803

Comment: Right, but I am looking for a way to filter that out using JS. Like some if statement that catches Fullscreen resizes and doesnt apply the above rules

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned two issues, here is how I fixed the same two issues (with help from other answers etc):

1 Fix "on mobile devices any scrolling is triggering [resize]":

We do this by keeping track of `windowWidth` and only triggering what we want to happen on an actual resize when the `windowWidth` changes. I also use a small delay (800 ms) to wait for the user to finish resizing if they are dragging.

```
function doneResizing() {
    something.refresh();
};

//Call doneResizing on re-size of the window
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){
    // Check width has actually changed (not just iOS
    // triggering resize event on scroll)
    if ($(window).width() != windowWidth) {
        // Update the window width for next time
        windowWidth = $(window).width();
        clearTimeout(id);
        id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 800);
    }
});
```

2 "I want users to be able to fullscreen the YouTube video..."

Keep track of whether the user is in fullscreen mode (using `var fullscreen = false;` and `fullscreenchange` etc) and only do the resizing stuff if not in fullscreen:

```
var fullscreen = false;

$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
  fullscreen = (window.screenTop == 0 && window.screenY == 0);
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if (!fullscreen) {
        // resizing stuff
    }
});
```

3 All-together now:

```
function doneResizing() {
    something.refresh();
};

var id; // used for doneResizing clearTimeout
var fullscreen = false;

$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    fullscreen = (window.screenTop == 0 && window.screenY == 0);
});

//Call doneResizing on re-size of the window
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){
    if (!fullscreen) {
        // Check width has actually changed (not just iOS triggering resize event on scroll)
        if ($(window).width() != windowWidth) {
            windowWidth = $(window).width(); // Update the window width for next time
            clearTimeout(id);
            id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 800);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue in my development as well. 
I fixed it with fairly simple solution - compare the height of `video` element(`iframe` that contains the video if it's not from origin) with `screen.height`, which is the height of the display. If they are same, then just ignore fresh.

```
var heights = $("iframe").map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get();

maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
// find the maximum height among videos
if(maxHeight != screen.height) {
    location.reload();
}
```